# Kotlin coroutines progress counter

Tags: kotlin, counter, progress, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I'm making thousands of HTTP requests using async/await and would like to have a progress indicator. I've added one in a naive way, but noticed that the counter value never reaches the total when all requests are done. So I've created a simple test and, sure enough, it doesn't work as expected:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var i = 0
    val range = (1..100000)
    range.map {
        launch {
            ++i
        }
    }
    println("$i ${range.count()}")
}
```

The output is something like this, where the first number always changes:

```
98800 100000
```

I'm probably missing some important detail about concurrency/synchronization in JVM/Kotlin, but don't know where to start. Any tips?

UPDATE: I ended up using channels as Marko suggested:

```
/**
 * Asynchronously fetches stats for all symbols and sends a total number of requests
 * to the `counter` channel each time a request completes. For example:
 *
 *     val counterActor = actor<Int>(UI) {
 *         var counter = 0
 *         for (total in channel) {
 *             progressLabel.text = "${++counter} / $total"
 *         }
 *     }
 */
suspend fun getAssetStatsWithProgress(counter: SendChannel<Int>): Map<String, AssetStats> {
    val symbolMap = getSymbols()?.let { it.map { it.symbol to it }.toMap() } ?: emptyMap()
    val total = symbolMap.size
    return symbolMap.map { async { getAssetStats(it.key) } }
        .mapNotNull { it.await().also { counter.send(total) } }
        .map { it.symbol to it }
        .toMap()
}
```

Comment: I noticed that `launch(Unconfined)` does the trick for me in this simplistic example, but  from the coroutines guide: "Unconfined dispatcher is appropriate when coroutine does not consume CPU time nor updates any shared data (like UI) that is confined to a specific thread" and I'm definitely doing both :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation what exactly makes your wrong approach fail is secondary: the primary thing is fixing the approach.

Instead of `async-await` or `launch`, for this communication pattern you should instead have an `actor` to which all the HTTP jobs send their status. This will automatically handle all your concurrency issues.

Here's some sample code, taken from the link you provided in the comment and adapted to your use case. Instead of some third party asking it for the counter value and updating the GUI with it, the actor runs in the UI context and updates the GUI itself:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.channels.*
import kotlin.system.*
import kotlin.coroutines.experimental.*

object IncCounter

fun counterActor() = actor<IncCounter>(UI) {
    var counter = 0
    for (msg in channel) {
        updateView(++counter)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    val counter = counterActor()
    massiveRun(CommonPool) {
        counter.send(IncCounter)
    }
    counter.close()
    println("View state: $viewState")
}


// Everything below is mock code that supports the example
// code above:

val UI = newSingleThreadContext("UI")

fun updateView(newVal: Int) {
    viewState = newVal
}

var viewState = 0

suspend fun massiveRun(context: CoroutineContext, action: suspend () -> Unit) {
    val numCoroutines = 1000
    val repeatActionCount = 1000
    val time = measureTimeMillis {
        val jobs = List(numCoroutines) {
            launch(context) {
                repeat(repeatActionCount) { action() }
            }
        }
        jobs.forEach { it.join() }
    }
    println("Completed ${numCoroutines * repeatActionCount} actions in $time ms")
}
```

Running it prints

```
Completed 1000000 actions in 2189 ms
View state: 1000000
```

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a code snippet. I just tried using an actor with a counter in it (similar to the way it's done there https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#actors)  and ran into the same issue.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for posting a code snippet. Since I also want to show the total, I replaced the `IncCounter` with simply `Int` which is the number of async requests we are about to perform. So I simply send this same number to the channel every time a request completes. No special type  is required and we can do `updateView("${++counter} / $msg")`. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You're losing writes because `i++` is not an atomic operation - the value has to be read, incremented, and then written back - and you have multiple threads reading and writing `i` at the same time. (If you don't provide `launch` with a context, it uses a threadpool by default.)

You're losing 1 from your count every time two threads read the same value as they will then both write that value plus one.

Synchronizing in some way, for example by using an `AtomicInteger` solves this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val i = AtomicInteger(0)
    val range = (1..100000)
    range.map {
        launch {
            i.incrementAndGet()
        }
    }
    println("$i ${range.count()}") // 100000 100000
}
```

There's also no guarantee that these background threads will be done with their work by the time you print the result and your program ends - you can test it easily by adding just a very small delay inside `launch`, a couple milliseconds. With that, it's a good idea to wrap this all in a `runBlocking` call which will keep the main thread alive and then wait for the coroutines to all finish:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    val i = AtomicInteger(0)
    val range = (1..100000)
    val jobs: List<Job> = range.map {
        launch {
            i.incrementAndGet()
        }
    }
    jobs.forEach { it.join() }
    println("$i ${range.count()}") // 100000 100000
}
```

Comment: Note that `count()` is somewhat inefficient for ranges since it iterates over all values.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [Coroutines basics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/coroutines-basic-jvm.html#lets-run-a-lot-of-them)? There's exact same problem as yours:

> ```
> val c = AtomicInteger()
>
> for (i in 1..1_000_000)
>     launch {
>         c.addAndGet(i)
>     }
>
> println(c.get())
> ```
>
> This example completes in less than a second for me, but it prints some arbitrary number, because some coroutines don't finish before main() prints the result.

Because `launch` is not blocking, there's no guarantee all of coroutines will finish before `println`. You need to use `async`, store the `Deferred` objects and `await` for them to finish.